# cin.ignore alternative, clear EVERYTHING in buffer

Tags: c++

Is there an alternative to using something like `cin.ignore(10000, '\n')`?
For example, I'm asking for a first name, and the user starts typing his 100 page life story on one line without hitting enter. There is no way to know exactly how long the user will keep going for, is there a catch all in C++ to dump all user input until the next prompt? I have searched around, all the suggestions say to throw an arbitrarily large number in the `cin.ignore` argument.

Is there a reliable way to code:

```
while cin.get(variable, #, delimiter) is in a fail state;
{
    use cin.ignore() until there is nothing left in the buffer;
}

cin.clear()
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Just specify the maximum stream size

```
std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max()
```

Since it's an unsigned type, you could sacrifice explicitness for brevity and just say `-1`.

Comment: Where does the -1 come into play? I tried std::cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n'); and it works, with the desired effect in this case.

Comment: @user3363001: When converted to an unsigned type, `-1` becomes the maximum value of that type (since the conversion is done by modular arithmetic). So you can just write that, if you don't feel like writing the longer `numeric_limits` expression.

Answer (score 0):

Use [`std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/numeric_limits/max):

```
std::cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');
```